# What's the equivalent for SecureString in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In the .NET API for Windows Store Apps the SecureString class is missing. Also PasswordBox does not store the password in a secure string. What's the equivalent to store strings securely in a Windows Store App? Or do Windows 8 have some secure mechanism to prevent others from reading the application's memory (or memory dump after deliberately crashed)

Comment: A related answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winappswithcsharp/thread/4f5ca16e-a04c-4fa6-9908-ea9e0a24b788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none.  The omissions in the .NET api for Store apps were made either because a class just could not work in a WinRT app because it relied on unavailable OS support, because the opportunity was there to cut some dead wood in the framework or because the class just plain doesn't make sense in a Store application.

The omission of SecureString heavily favors the "doesn't make sense" explanation.  No attacker would ever go through the trouble of trying to dig the string out of multiple gigabytes of swap file data.  It is **much** easier to just download your app from the store and use a debugger in the comfort of his own home.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I take that as an answer. But I am not really sure that the "doesn't make sense" case really applies. That would mean SecureString does not make sense in a desktop app as well. Why was it then implemented in the first place? I could imagine that heavily secured environments (governments) enforce a policy to not store passwords in clear text. And I could imagine that a Windows Store App could make sense in these environments. I am not sure but isn't it possible to crash an app and search in the memory dump (much easier than searching swap files)?

Comment: There's no substitute for physical security, no amount of software security can work without it. At least with a desktop app you have a shot at it, you can control its distribution. That government agency needs good locks and has to make sure nobody goes rummaging through the garbage bins. SecureString addresses the garbage bin problem.  There is none whatsoever when it is deployed through a Store that anybody can get to.

Comment: I totally agree that there is no substitute for physical security. But as with Windows Store Apps you can control the distribution too when installing it not from the Store but using sideloading I don't see much difference to desktop apps in terms of security. I believe that installing apps directly to machines will be a common scenario in the future for certain companies. I work for a company that already did this (app for managers that displays business data).

Comment: @JürgenBayer, you *can* but that does not mean that it's something Microsoft cares much about. For the ultra-secure institution crowd, there still are Windows Desktop apps. Also, WinRT apps are already sandboxed, so that is a layer of security in itself. Sandboxing also solves the garbage bin problem, but in another way.